# JavaScript: Possible outcomes of error event on XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This question regards the `error` event on the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

The MDN documentation website tells me the following:

> The error event is fired when a resource failed to load.

What are all of the possible causes for a resource to fail to load, and how do I check for these causes on the error object?

**Edit #1**

Perhaps a slight modification of my question is in order, basically what I want to know is why would I want to add a listener for the `error` event, and what should I do if it is triggered? I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to talk to my REST API. I assume that one of the possible outcomes is something like "Can't connect to server" in the case of the server being offline. Is there a list somewhere that I can use as a reference for these error strings/return values of the `error` event?

Comment: All of them? That would be a short book. I'm sure you know most conditions, which ones are you concerned about? If you don't have a piece of code that is misbehaving, the question may not be a good fit for stack overflow. Broader questions that lead to debates are a better fit for programmers stack exchange.

Comment: @JuanMendes I've edited my question to make it somewhat more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are [multiple conditions](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#suggested-names-for-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) to be aware of. The events have different event types and are all of type [`ProgressEvent`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#progressevent)

- **error**: Progression failed.    Zero or once (mutually exclusive).  After the last progress has been dispatched.
- **abort**: Progression is terminated.
- **timeout**: Progression is terminated due to preset time expiring.

For ProgressEvents of type error, you can look at [`XMLHttpRequest.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) which is an [HTTP error code](http://httpstatusdogs.com/) such as (404, 409, 500) and you can look at [`XMLHttpRequest.responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/statusText) which could have strings such as "OK" or "Not Found".

For HTTP status codes, the 400s are errors on the client side (invalid input/request) and 500s are for server errors.